# python flask before_first_request_funcs

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

In my python3 flask application I would like to execute a couple of recurring tasks before the first request.
In order to achieve this, I want to make use of the`@app.before_first_request_funcs`.

Can anyone please give me an example usage of `@app.before_first_request_funcs`?

Here is my sample code:

```py
import threading
import time

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


def activate_job():
    def run_job():
        while True:
            print("recurring task")
            time.sleep(3)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_job())
    thread.start()


def activate_job2():
    def run_job2():
        while True:
            print("recurring task2")
            time.sleep(3)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_job2())
    thread.start()


@app.after_first_request(activate_job())
@app.before_first_request(activate_job2())
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return {"action": "This has done something"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(app.before_first_request_funcs)
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request_funcs), you should use `@app.before_first_request` to do what you want.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
def some_func(some_arg):
    print('coucou')

# @app.before_first_request(some_func)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return {"action" : "This has done something"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(app.before_first_request_funcs)
    app.run()
```

You can see the behavior of the **method** `before_first_request_funcs` that is **not** a decorator by commenting and uncommenting the **decorator** `before_first_request`.

If it is commented, it'll print an empty list, and if you uncomment the line, it'll return a list of one element containing the function `some_func` object (for me, it was `[<function some_func at 0x0000021393A0AD90>]`).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
i have to call 2 functions before the first request. Both of these functions should be recurring (kind of daemons that monitor the DB/files). When i modified my program as per your answer, i never reach to @app.before_first_request(activate_job2())
? the program keeps printing "recurring task" and never reaches the second function. 
can you please suggest?

-

Comment: @Siddharthvij You should send the **function** itself, and not its return value. Take the parenthesis away such as you do `activate_job2` instead of `activate_job2()`.

Comment: i have modified the query to add the code. can you please suggest having a glance at this code?

Comment: I already told you to change the lines of `activate_jobs()` by `activate_jobs`.

Comment: The `before_first_request` decorator has been deprecated and [removed](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/) as of version 2.3.0.

Answer (score 7):

As Damien stated in the comments section, `app.before_first_request` and `bp.before_app_first_request` decorators have been [removed starting with 2.3](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0)

- Stackoverflow question that addressed the refactoring process: [Flask deprecated before_first_request how to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570041/flask-deprecated-before-first-request-how-to-update)