# Flask deprecated before_first_request how to update

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning web development for simple applications and I've created one that uses `before_first_request` decorator. According with the new release notes, the before_first_request is deprecated and will be [removed](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/) from Flask 2.3:

> Deprecated since version 2.2: Will be removed in Flask 2.3. Run setup
> code when creating the application instead.

I don't understand how I can update my code to be complacent with Flask 2.3 and still run a function at first request without using before_first_request. Could some kind soul give me an example?

Comment: switch to using the Application Factory Pattern and put whatever you did in the `before_first_request` into the init code of the Flask app. See [this excellent guide](https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory/) on how to set up a Flask app using AFP

Answer (score 31):

I don't know if this is answered but for anyone looking for the answer:

in place of the `@app.before_first_request` decorated function use the app instance like this:
i.e.

```
# In place of something like this
@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
    ...

# push context manually to app
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

Comment: My code is executing twice within this (I'm just printing "hello, world"). Any ideas why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: ^ Fixed it. It was because my app was running with Debug=true, you'll have to set it to false so it doesn't run twice.

Comment: This gives me an error - "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context."

Comment: where exactly do you execute that with statement if using the application factory pattern?

Comment: Thanks @anthonyjdella Your Fixed comment saved my day!

Comment: this also works for `quart` but make sure to use async

Answer (score 3):

`@app.before_first_request` can be replicated simply with a single additional line of code to remove the handler from the app.

```
@app.before_request
def create_tables():
    # The following line will remove this handler, making it
    # only run on the first request
    app.before_request_funcs[None].remove(create_tables)

    db.create_all()
```

Comment: This worked better than "with app.app_context():" for me because the code I am running attempts to call multiprocessing.Manager(). this will fail if the process is just starting, as it will be if "with app.app_context()" is running outside of a function. The pattern shown here allows process creation to finish and only calls my code when the first request comes in

Comment: It also won't slow down loading of the app in non-web contexts, such as in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

We could manually track if the first request has been made before in a bool such as `appHasRunBefore` using the still available `@app.before_request`

```py
appHasRunBefore:bool = False

@app.before_request
def firstRun():
    global appHasRunBefore
    if not appHasRunBefore:
        # Run any of your code here
        thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_alive, args=())
        thread.start()
        # Set the bool to True so this method isn't called again
        appHasRunBefore = True
```

We can then run any code if it is the first request.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using `pytest` to test the API and the package `flask_monitoringdashboard` to monitor my app performance, but the latest version of this last package uses the `before_first_request` method in the code.

The package team solved this issue one month ago in [this commit](https://github.com/flask-dashboard/Flask-MonitoringDashboard/commit/40530882d2298b4601e4e95e4b6a9a760be32b96), but they do not release a new version of the package until now.

1. You can solve this problem manually by applying the upper commit to the package code.
2. You can suppress the warning like the below:

```py
import warnings
import flask_monitoringdashboard as monitoring_dashboard
from your_package import create_app()


app = create_app()
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    monitoring_dashboard.config.init_from(file=flask_monitoring_file_path)
    monitoring_dashboard.bind(app)
```

3. If you are having this issue with pytest, try to not execute the code that binds the app with the dashboard in your tests, like not having the binding code in the create_app function.

Answer (score -2):

```py
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    my_fun()
```

can be replaced with

```py
app.before_request_funcs = [(None, my_fun())]
```

`my_fun()` will be run before any request.

Comment: `my_fun()` will be run once, at the assignment of the variable and never again!  But more, this runs EVERY request - the question wants to run once, on the FIRST request.