# Run a function while initializing the python flask server

Tags: python, flask

I want to run a function when initializing the server to get data from the stored api to the server for later use, but when I use @app.before_first_request it gives me an error. I use Python Flask version 2.3.3

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    fetch_data_from_apis()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

it gives error " @app.before_first_request
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'before_first_request'. Did you mean: '_got_first_request'?"

Comment: `before_first_request` has been [removed since Flask 2.3.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask deprecated before\_first\_request how to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570041/flask-deprecated-before-first-request-how-to-update)

Answer (score 0):

From flask 2.3.0: `The app.before_first_request and bp.before_app_first_request decorators are removed.` You can use `before_request` to handle data

Comment: Link changelog https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0