# AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'before_first_request' in Flask 3.x

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to run init function when flask app run.
Here's `server.py`:

```
from .parser import Parser
app = Flask(config().get("FLASK_APP"))

parser = None

@app.before_first_request
def init():
  parser = Parser()
```

Here's `wsgi.py`:

```
import logging
from src.utils.config import config

host = config().get("FLASK_HOST")
port = config().get("FLASK_PORT")
env = config().get("FLASK_ENV")
is_dev = env == "dev"
logging.basicConfig(
  format='[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(message)s]',
  level=logging.INFO if is_dev else logging.WARNING,
  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
)

from src.api.server import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
    host=host, 
    port=port,
    debug=is_dev,
    threaded=True 
  )
```

And i'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'before_first_request'`.
When i'm running the `server.py` like this:

```
from .parser import Parser
app = Flask(config().get("FLASK_APP"))

parser = Parser()
```

The parser runs twice.

I'm using Flask 3.0.0, as i see this decorator is deprecated.
Are there any other solutions for Flask 3.0.0 version?

I've checked the flask documentation but didn't find any alternatives for `before_first_request` decorator.

Comment: The decorator has been removed from Flask since [version 2.3.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-0). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570041/flask-deprecated-before-first-request-how-to-update) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddenly i found the solution. The problem as i see is in the flask's reloader, so i just disabled this feature in the app.run bootstrap function.
Here's detailed info by Sean's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476701/11988818 
For now, my application runs once. And there's no needs in the `before_first_request` decorator anymore.